# vb.net web form generates extra blank lines

Tags: asp.net, telerik, vb.net-2010, telerik-grid

In a vb.net 2010 web form application the user loads 'template letters' to a web 
     interface, that they can modify letters sent out to various customers to generate
     various late pay notifications. The user basically selects the 'template letter' they want
      to generate for a specific customer, and hits the 'save' button.

The web interface has the tabs for 'preview', 'html', and 'design' as the bottom of 
       editor.      These tabs are not part of any custom code, they must be part of a web 
      interface that is inherited.

The values for the editor are stored in a sql server 2012 database in a field 
      called 'strTemplate' and the value is actually html.

The problem is once the html value for 'strTemplate' is loaded for the user to edit, extra  blank lines are loaded between different parts of  the 'templates. Basically extra `<br></br>` tags are generated.

When the user hits the save button, more `<br></br>` tags are generated between the various parts of the letter.

I do not want these extra blank lines to be generated.

I have gone into the html tab, removed the `<br></br>` tags and hit the save button. The extra tags are still generated. I have stepped through the code to find where the tags are generated and can not find it.

Thus can you tell me what I can do to not have the extra  `<br></br>` tags generated?

The following is some of the code that is used when accessing the part of that gets to the web interface:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports Telerik.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.Script.Services
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
Imports System.Web.Services


Partial Class edittemplates_default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected _master As MasterPage

#Region "Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load"

    Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        _master = CType(Page.Master, MasterPage)
        _master.PageTitle = "Edit Templates"
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            If (edittemplates_default.SiteUserManager.SessionUser IsNot Nothing) Then
                LoadTemplates()
                LoadVariables()
            Else
                'pnlEditor.Enabled = False
                'pnlEditor.Visible = False            
            End If
        End If
        Master.Page.Title = "Login"
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region "Protected Sub LoadTemplates()"
    Protected Sub LoadTemplates()
        Dim et As EditTemplates = New EditTemplates()
        Dim dt As DataTable = et.SelectTemplates()
        For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count() - 1
            ddlTemplates.Items.Add(New ListItem(dt.Rows(i)(dt.Columns(1).ColumnName()), dt.Rows(i)(dt.Columns(0).ColumnName())))
        Next
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region "Protected Sub LoadVariables()"

    Protected Sub LoadVariables()
        Dim et As EditTemplates = New EditTemplates()
        Dim dt As DataTable = et.SelectAtnLtrVariables()
        For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count() - 1
            rlbVariables.Items.Add(New RadListBoxItem(dt.Rows(i)(dt.Columns(1).ColumnName()), dt.Rows(i)(dt.Columns(0).ColumnName())))
        Next
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region "Protected Sub btnSaveTemplate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSaveTemplate.Click"

    Protected Sub btnSaveTemplate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSaveTemplate.Click
        Dim et As EditTemplates = New EditTemplates()
        If ddlTemplates.SelectedValue <> 0 Then
            et.UpdateTemplate(ddlTemplates.SelectedValue, ddlLanguage.SelectedValue, rEditor.Content.ToString())
        End If
    End Sub

#End Region
-------------------
Partial Class edittemplates_default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected _master As MasterPage
-----------
```

Comment: As much as I've tried to format your posted code for readability, none of it seems related to your question. A Google search for [Telerik RadEditor adding additional `<br></br>` tags with each postback](http://www.telerik.com/forums/ie9-and-radeditor-adding-additional-lt-br-gt-lt-br-gt-tags-with-each-postback) seems promising - hth.

Comment: Step into a debugger and see if  rEditor.Content has the expected HTML and if not - something in the data access layer is messing up the HTML. If they come from the editor - see the search above. You can also try setting ContentFilters to None to see if one of them is causing it. Generally, try upgrading your Telerik UI for ASP.NET AJAX version to the latest as this may be a bug in a browser that is no supported in your current version.

Comment: I will check into these items

Answer (score 1):

You are using a very old version of RadEditor, which does not support IE9 where the reported problem exists. To fix the problem it is recommended to upgrade to the latest Q2 2014 version, which will ensure that the editor will function as expected in all modern browsers.

You can also verify that the problem is fixed in the online demos of RadEditor: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/saveindatabase/defaultcs.aspx